# How to make javascript code to work witn node.js?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, src

I have the following code and I know that if I use it in the terminal (node test.js, in the case the file is called test.js) but how do I make this code work in javascript with HTML? I mean, how do I make possible to click a button and execute the code? Thank you!

```
var SerialPort = require("serialport").SerialPort
var serialPort = new SerialPort("/dev/ttyACM0", {
    baudrate: 9600
}, false);
serialPort.on('error', function(err) {
    console.log(err);
});
serialPort.open(function(err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return;
    }
    console.log('open');
    serialPort.on('data', function(data) {
        console.log('data received: ' + data);
    });
    serialPort.write('1', function(err, results) {});
});
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't execute this in a browser (which wouldn't let you access the serial port, for example) but there are various solutions to package some HTML code with nodejs.

The best solution today for a local all-including "desktop-type" architecture is probably [node-webkit](https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit) which has a good support and traction.

Another standard architecture is to simply make nodejs act as a server serving an HTML page including your button. That might be more suited for piloting an Arduino.